# Assign values of an Int to two separate variables

Tags: ios, swift, string, int

say for example i have an Int `var firstInt = 23` what i need is i want to assign the value of `firstInt` to two separate variables so the output would be `var x = 2` and `var y = 3`. i tried converting the `firstInt` to a string like so `var strFirstInt = String(firstInt)` and wanted to assign the first index of the string to a different variable and the second index to another variable and convert them to Int but i couldn't pick the string by index. so any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .compactMap from String like this :

```
let numberInt = 23
let digits = String(numberInt).compactMap{ $0.wholeNumberValue}
```

Response :

```
[2, 3]
```

And with this array, you put the first member to the first var and seconds to another:

```
var x = digits[0]
var y = digits[1]

print("The decade is \(x) and units is \(y)")
```

Response:

```
The decade is 2 and units is 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `firstInt` to `String` and then to `Array`,

```
var firstInt = 23
let arr = Array(String(firstInt)).map({ String($0 )})
```

Next, get the elements as per the `index` from `array`, i.e.

```
var x = Int(arr[0])
var y = Int(arr[1])
```